# Replace pandas df text

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I'm using python3 and pandas I need to replace my file slashes from "" TO "/"

```
df = pandas.read_csv(file)

df2 = df.drop(columns=['Name'])
df2 = df2[['MD5', 'FullName']]

df2.replace(to_replace="\\", value="/")
```

The above seems like it should work but its not replacing anything? - also the only column I really need to have this replaced in is 'FullName' if thats possible.

Comment: `df2['FullName'] = df2['FullName'].str.replace("\\","/")` ? related doc: https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.Series.str.replace.html

Comment: @anky. Please reopen the question, the problem is with escape backslash not how to use the `replace` method.

Comment: @Corralien thanks, it is actually both and the solution I suggested in my comments should work , if you refer `also the only column I really need to have this replaced in is 'FullName' if thats possible` it asks for str.replace. added the dupe for backlash too

Comment: @anky. I'm agree `but its not replacing anything` (probably) mean there is a problem with `'\\'`.

Comment: OK... All the questions in StackOverflow on Pandas should be close because if you merge all answers you will always get the right solution :-)

Comment: @Corralien Nope, I only closed this question because OP specially asked for a single column for which the solution I suggested works with the same pattern which OP had. Also I am not merging any answers, the single answer in the comment works with OP's pattern